# httparty: how to log request?

Tags: ruby, logging, httprequest, httparty

How do I log requests being sent with with httparty?

```
HTTParty.post(
          @application_url,
          :headers => {
            "Accept"        => "application/json",
            "Content-Type"  => "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          },
          :body => {
            "ApplicationProfileId" => application.applicationProfileId
          }.to_json
        )
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [`debug_output`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#debug_output-instance_method) at the class level:

```
class Foo
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout
end
```

or per request

```
response = HTTParty.post(url, :body => body, :debug_output => $stdout)
```

Comment: Nice, nobody else seems to know how to do it per request

Comment: Watch out: If you dig a little deeper into the Net::HTTP library it's based onto, you'll realize this should never be used in production
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-set_debug_output

Comment: So i would recommend:
`SomeLogger.info(HTTParty.get(uri, query: parameters).request.last_uri)`

Answer (score 6):

You ca use a built-in logger:

```
my_logger = Rails.logger || Logger.new # use what you like
my_logger.info "The default formatter is :apache. The :curl formatter can also be used."
my_logger.info "You can tell which method to call on the logger too. It is info by default."

HTTParty.get "http://google.com", logger: my_logger, log_level: :debug, log_format: :curl
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the class-level [`debug_output`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#debug_output-instance_method) method to set an output stream where debugging information gets sent.

Comment: Is it possible to use `Rails.logger` with `debug_output`?

Comment: `debug_output Rails.logger` works in Rails 4, but does not work in Rails 3 (apparently the Rails 3 version is missing an implementation for the `<<` operator).

Comment: @VishalVijay: This works in Rails 3, though the format is slightly different than with `debug_output`: `logger Rails.logger, :debug, :curl`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting in Rails console, you can turn on debug logging for all HTTParty Requests with:

```rb
HTTParty::Basement.debug_output $stdout
```